# Benefit of using SFP ports for switch to switch link in the same rack?

Tags: networking

Are there any benefits (other than mitigation of EMI) for using the SFP ports to connect 2 switches that are in the same rack.

Both of the port are 1000BASE-X, where as the copper RJ45 ports are 1000BASE-T.

Is there any reason i would use the SFP ports over the copper ports in this instance.